# How to use the header of a second data.frame as axis of a line plot using information of a first data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, linechart, linegraph, line-plot

After reading in my data in R I have two R internal variables, `Goats` and `GoatPositions`, that look like this:

```
> Goats
  GPS_No Goat_ID GoatName
1      5  660294    SIVKA
2      6  777077     MESI
3      7  660300   TONAKA
4      8  630328   ISKREA
5      9  608418    RIBEA
6     10  660290      OTA
```

and

```
> GoatPositions
  2020-07-13 18:00:00 2020-07-14 08:00:00 2020-07-14 18:00:00 2020-07-15 08:00:00
1                  33                  46                  NA                  44
2                  71                  59                  57                  71
3                  55                  NA                  40                  50
4                  18                  61                  24                  62
5                  53                   0                  44                   1
6                   4                  54                  54                  52
```

The `data.frame`s of both R variables have more rows and the variable `GoatPositions` has also more columns.

What I would like to do, is to plot the data in the following way:

- It should be a line graph.
- The `header` (column names) of `GoatPositions` should be the x-axes.
- The variables in the individual cells of `GoatPositions` should be the values for the y-axes.

(At the moment the label for the y-axis is nowhere indicated. It is going to be "Positions".)

- Every row should be plotted as an individual line.
- The line labels should be the values of the "GoatName" column in the `Goats` `data.frame`.

Of course, `?plot` describes its usage:
plot(x, y, type, main, xlab, ylab),
and data referencing in R works as follows:
`variablename[ row_conditions , column_conditions ]`

So, adapting from that gives:

```
plot(GoatPositions[,0:3], GoatPositions[0:5,], type="l", {linelab=Goats$GoatName})
```

Of course `{linelab=Goats$GoatName}` is placeholder pseudo-code and it does also not run if the {} brackets are removed, but my question which emerges from here on forward is:

How to use the `header` of a second `data.frame` as axis of a line plot using information of a first `data.frame` in R?

---

### Edit

Thanks to the comment from @Eyayaw I could run some code:

```
GoatPositionsLong <- reshape(GoatPositions, direction = 'long', timevar = 'date', varying = list(1:NCOL(GoatPositions)), times = colnames(GoatPositions), v.names = 'goat_pos')
Goats <- cbind(Goats, 1:nrow(Goats))
names(Goats)[names(Goats)=="1:nrow(Goats)"] <- "id"
GoatMerged <- merge(GoatPositionsLong, Goats, by = "id")
```

The variable `GoatMerged` looks now like this:

```
> GoatMerged
    id                date goat_pos GPS_No Goat_ID GoatName
1    1 2020-07-13 18:00:00       33      5  660294    SIVKA
2    1 2020-07-18 08:00:00      102      5  660294    SIVKA
...
14   2 2020-07-15 08:00:00       71      6  777077     MESI
15   2 2020-07-17 18:00:00       79      6  777077     MESI
...
27   3 2020-07-15 08:00:00       50      7  660300   TONAKA
28   3 2020-07-14 18:00:00       40      7  660300   TONAKA
```

with a total of 117 rows. Now, if I try to plot this:

```
plot(GoatMerged$date, GoatMerged$goat_pos, type="l")
```

I still get errors:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : finite 'xlim' values necessary
Additional warnings:
1: In min(x) : no no-missing argument for min; give Inf back
2: In max(x) : no no-missing argument for max; give -Inf back
```

Thank you @Eyayaw for your comment!

Yet, now I still want to ask: How to plot the now long format structured data?

---

### Edit 2

Thanks to the further comment of @Eyayaw I checked the class of `GoatMerged$date` and made changes accordingly:

```
> class(GoatMerged$date)
[1] "character"

> GoatMerged$date <- as.POSIXct(GoatMerged$date, tz="Europe/Ljubljana")

> class(GoatMerged$date)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

> plot(GoatMerged$date, GoatMerged$goat_pos, type="l")
```

The resulted plot that I get is this:
[image: GoatPositionsOverTime]

The issue with this plot is that it does not look like the desired one:

[image: GoatPositionsOverTimeDesired]

That raises the question: Why does the plot command try to read out the weekdates of the dates and plot the data as a time loop (?) instead of the individual time points?
So, how to plot `DateTime / "POSIXct" "POSIXt"` data in a 'sequence of time points' manner?

---

### Edit 3

As asked from @Eyayaw here is the output of

```
> dput(GoatMerged)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), date = structure(c(1626192000, 
1626588000, 1626710400, 1626537600, 1626364800, 1626415200, 1626674400, 
1626501600, 1626242400, 1626624000, 1626328800, 1626451200, 1626278400, 
1626328800, 1626537600, 1626278400, 1626710400, 1626501600, 1626364800, 
1626674400, 1626451200, 1626192000, 1626242400, 1626624000, 1626415200, 
1626588000, 1626328800, 1626278400, 1626710400, 1626537600, 1626364800, 
1626242400, 1626674400, 1626501600, 1626451200, 1626192000, 1626624000, 
1626588000, 1626415200, 1626710400, 1626328800, 1626624000, 1626674400, 
1626537600, 1626278400, 1626501600, 1626364800, 1626242400, 1626588000, 
1626451200, 1626192000, 1626415200, 1626588000, 1626415200, 1626242400, 
1626624000, 1626364800, 1626192000, 1626451200, 1626710400, 1626537600, 
1626278400, 1626674400, 1626501600, 1626328800, 1626501600, 1626710400, 
1626451200, 1626328800, 1626674400, 1626537600, 1626415200, 1626624000, 
1626364800, 1626242400, 1626278400, 1626588000, 1626192000, 1626501600, 
1626328800, 1626278400, 1626710400, 1626451200, 1626415200, 1626242400, 
1626674400, 1626537600, 1626364800, 1626192000, 1626624000, 1626588000, 
1626328800, 1626501600, 1626278400, 1626674400, 1626710400, 1626451200, 
1626242400, 1626537600, 1626415200, 1626192000, 1626624000, 1626364800, 
1626588000, 1626624000, 1626451200, 1626588000, 1626278400, 1626674400, 
1626415200, 1626242400, 1626501600, 1626537600, 1626364800, 1626192000, 
1626328800, 1626710400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Ljubljana"), 
    goat_pos = c(33L, 102L, 55L, 42L, 50L, 50L, 42L, 28L, 46L, 
    28L, 44L, 29L, NA, 71L, 79L, 57L, 88L, 86L, 78L, 78L, 51L, 
    71L, 59L, 78L, 69L, 78L, 50L, 40L, 52L, 53L, 55L, NA, 46L, 
    54L, 60L, 55L, 58L, 56L, 48L, 61L, 62L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 24L, 
    44L, 19L, 61L, 81L, 81L, 18L, 81L, 22L, 6L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 53L, 
    5L, 8L, 20L, 44L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 48L, 27L, 64L, 52L, 52L, 69L, 
    52L, 34L, 46L, 54L, 54L, 33L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
    NA, 5L, 1L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 28L, 61L, 53L, 45L, 47L, 35L, 
    37L, 41L, 40L, 49L, 31L, 40L, 28L, 101L, 99L, 99L, 83L, 99L, 
    102L, 81L, 102L, 103L, 98L, 81L, 81L, 103L), GPS_No = c(5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), Goat_ID = c(660294L, 
    660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 
    660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 660294L, 777077L, 777077L, 
    777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 
    777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 777077L, 660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 
    660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 
    660300L, 660300L, 660300L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 
    630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 630328L, 
    630328L, 630328L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 
    608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 608418L, 
    608418L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 
    660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 660290L, 
    611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 
    611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 611145L, 457088L, 
    457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 
    457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 457088L, 611254L, 611254L, 
    611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 
    611254L, 611254L, 611254L, 611254L), GoatName = c("SIVKA", 
    "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", 
    "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "SIVKA", "MESI", "MESI", 
    "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", 
    "MESI", "MESI", "MESI", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", 
    "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", 
    "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "TONÄŒKA", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", 
    "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", 
    "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "ISKREÅ ", "RIBEÅ½", 
    "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", 
    "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", "RIBEÅ½", 
    "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", 
    "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "OTA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", 
    "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", 
    "ZAJKA", "ZAJKA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", 
    "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", "BRINA", 
    "BRINA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", 
    "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA", "TISA"), 
    EarStatus = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
    "Control", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", "Short-ear", 
    "Short-ear", "Short-ear")), row.names = c(NA, -117L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need to reshape the `GoatPositions` data into what the `plot` function understands. Or to what is called `long format`. Try first this: `reshape(df, direction = 'long', timevar = 'date', varying = list(1:NCOL(df)), times = colnames(df), v.names = 'goat_pos')`. Replace `df` by `GoatPositions`. Then merge this reshaped data with the `Goats` data.frame.

Comment: You're almost there. What class is the `date` variable in GoatMerged? By the look of it, it should be `DateTime`. Do you need the time in the `date`? DateTime class in r is `class(Sys.time())`
`#> "POSIXct" "POSIXt" `

Comment: I meant you can keep only the date, i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd` with `as.Date(df$date)`.

Comment: @Eyayaw Thank you for all of your answers and your comments! Unfortunately yes, I need the time and date information simultaneously. Also, as the second picture now shows, this is required to communicate changes within the same day and allowing to see what data point refers to the morning and which to the evening.
But besides that, thank you for your suggestion of `as.Date(df$date)`!

Comment: I think it'd be better if you could post some part of your data. Can you do `dput(GoatMerged)` and then paste the result here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the base plot may involve writing `for loop` to color `goat_pos` by `GoatName`, i.e., color each line for each player, `ggplot2` would be easier. So here we go:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(goat, aes(date, goat_pos, color = as.factor(GoatName))) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 day') + 
    labs(color = 'Goats', y='Positions') +
    theme_classic()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjYPi.png)

Comment: I hope that is close enough to the plot you are trying to reproduce. You can change `date_breaks` according to your liking; e.g.,  2 days, 3 weeks etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and thank you very much for all your help!
Yes, this is in concept the plot I was aiming for. I may change the one or the other aesthetical thing like line width or so, but in general yes, this is what I was looking for - thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad you find it helpful. Cheers!